# Python module is not detected/known to C++ in embedding application

Tags: boost-python

I am writing a python embedding in C++ application. The related code snippet that I declare the module of python(user-defined one) that needs to be embedded as below:

```
boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
boost::python::exec("import python_module", main_namespace); //This line is the culprit
```

However, I'm stuck when I receive the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
```

My user-defined python module resides in the same directory as my C++ code. When I try like to use `numpy`that works, the problem is that only with my user-defined one, it doesn't. What could be done in order to debug it?

EDIT:

After I include the code in try/catch block, I obtained the following compile error:

```
ImportError: No module named python_module
```

I also try to add this:

```
boost::python::exec("import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/python_module.py');",  main_namespace);

boost::python::exec("import python_module", main_namespace);
```

but not yet working.

The problem now is how do I make it known to my C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a couple of things:

1. In your C++ app: `boost::python::exec("import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to'); import python_module; del sys"), main_namespace);`, or
2. In your shell: `cd /path/to; call-your-c++-app`. Then, in C++, you would need only to `boost::python::exec("import python_module");`, or
3. Set your environment variable to `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to:${PYTHONPATH}` and execute your program. Your C++ in this case would need only to `boost::python::exec("import python_module");` as in the above solution.

The issue: You need to append the path leading to the module to `sys.path` and **not** the path to the module file itself.

Another hint: by default, Python will load modules from the current directory. If you `cd` there and execute your application from that directory, it should find the module on the current directory.